# For Loop Structure in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

Is it possible to have  the following logic of a for loop in python?:

```
with  open("file_r", "r") as infile, open("file_1", 'w') as outfile_1, open("file_2", 'w') as outfile_2: 
    for result in re.findall('somestring(.*?)\}', infile.read(), re.S):
       for line in result.split('\n'):
           outfile_1.write(line) 

    for result in re.findall('sime_other_string(.*?)\}', infile.read(), re.S):
       for line in result.split('\n'):
           outfile_2.write(line)
```

I'm asking because the result of the first foor loop are written to the "outfile_1" file, but the results of the secund loop are empty in the "outfile_2" file.

Answer (score 3):

Save `infile.read()` into a variable else the file will be finished in the first loop itself. Say:

```
with  open("file_r", "r") as infile, open("file_1", 'w') as outfile_1, open("file_2", 'w') as outfile_2: 
    contents = infile.read()

    for result in re.findall('somestring(.*?)\}', contents, re.S):
       for line in result.split('\n'):
           outfile_1.write(line) 

    for result in re.findall('sime_other_string(.*?)\}', contents, re.S):
       for line in result.split('\n'):
           outfile_2.write(line)
```

Comment: And you could use comprehension to simplify the two loops.

Comment: Ouh! Thx a lot!! It works now with saving infile.read() to a variable!

Answer (score 0):

Only if you 'rewind' `infile` to the start again in between reads:

```
... infile.read()

infile.seek(0)

... infile.read()
```

A file is a lot like an audiotape; when you read a reading 'head' moves along the tape and returns the data. `file.seek()` moves the reading 'head' to a different position, `infile.seek(0)` moves it to the start again.

You'd be better off reading the file just *once* though:

```
content_of_infile = infile.read()

for result in re.findall('somestring(.*?)\}', content_of_infile, re.S):
    # ...

for result in re.findall('sime_other_string(.*?)\}', contents_of_infile, re.S):
    # ...
```